Are determinantal ideals Cohen-Macaulay?
Let $R=K[X_{ij}:i=1,\dots,m,j=1,\dots,n]$. The ideal in $R$ generated by all the $t$-minors of the $m\times n$ matrix
$$ X=\begin{pmatrix}
  X_{11} & X_{12} & \dots & X_{1n}\\
  X_{21} & \ X_{22} & \dots & X_{2n}\\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots\\
  X_{m1} & X_{m2} & \dots & X_{mn}
 \end{pmatrix}
 $$
is known as determinantal ideal of $X$, for every $2\leqslant t\leqslant \min\{m,n\}$.
Is it known that all determinantal ideals are Cohen-Macaulay or is there a counter-example?

Do you mean that the $X_{ij}$ are indeterminates, and the ideal is contained in $k[\lbrace X_{ij}\rbrace_{m,n}]$ for some field $k$? The question as it is is not clear. Also, you may add some of the ideas that you might have tried to solve this.

Yes, $X_{ij}$ are indeterminates... it looks that Hochster and Eagon solved it in https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2373744.pdf Do you agree with that?

I cannot check your reference right now, but yesterday thinking about your question, I found it on Bruns and Vetter's Determinantal rings, Theorem 2.5, https://www.home.uni-osnabrueck.de/wbruns/brunsw/detrings.pdf :) so I guess this closes the question! Should we write it down as an answer?

As we concluded in the comments, the answer is yes. Such rings defined by the determinant of a matrix of indeterminates are always Cohen–Macaulay as can be seen in this Hochster and Eagon's paper or Bruns and Vetter's Determinantal rings, Theorem 2.5. And actually, by Theorem 2.8 of the last reference, one sees that this is true not only with coefficients over a field $k$ but over any Cohen–Macaulay ring.
I think it is worth mentioning the following. A determinantal ideal is a more general kind of ideal, and they are always Cohen–Macaulay. Mainly, they are defined as ideals generated by minors of a matrix AND such that the height of the resulting ideal is the expected height (see Miro-Roig's monograph, definition 1.2.3.). I guess the interest of the definition relies on this second hypothesis, because if not, any ideal in a Noetherian ring could be realised as generated by minors of a matrix just by taking a $1\times n$ matrix whose components are the generators! Amusingly, by this same argument, one sees that complete intersections are determinantal rings. So determinantal rings lie between complete intersections and Cohen–Macaulay rings! Just as Gorenstein rings.
I am not an expert on this field, all of this I concluded from researching a bit because I found this interesting. Experts feel free to add anything.
